# robot framework with pabot : is it possible to pass two different values to a variable in two tests

Tags: python, robotframework

Example, I have `file1.robot` and `file2.robot`and each has `${var}` as the variable. Can I pass 2 different values to this same `${var}` in the command line? Something like `pabot -v var:one:two file1.robot file2.robot` where `-v var:one:two` would follow the order of the robot files; not by name but by how they were introduced in the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not 100% what you've asked for, but maybe you can make it work.

In [pabot readme file](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/blob/master/README.md) is mentioned something about shared set of variables and [acquiring set](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/blob/master/README.md#pabotlib) for each running process. The documentation was bit unclear to me, but if you try following example, you'll see for yourself. It's basically pool of variables and each process can get set of variables from it and when it's done with it, it can return this set back to the pool.

Create your value set `valueset.dat`

```
[Set1]
USERNAME=user1
PASSWORD=password1

[Set2]
USERNAME=user2
PASSWORD=password2
```

create `suite1.robot` and `suite2.robot`. I've created 2 suites that are exactly the same. I just wanted to try to run 2 suites in parallel.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    pabot.PabotLib

*** Test Cases ***
Foobar
    ${valuesetname}=    Acquire Value Set
    Log    ${valuesetname}
    ${username}=     Get Value From Set   username
    Log    ${username}
    # Release Value Set
```

And then run command `pabot --pabotlib --resourcefile valueset.dat tests`. If you check html report, you'll see that one suite used set1 and other used set2.

Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Comment: This is probably expected but wanted to ask just in case; the sets themselves are not used in any particular order, right? For example, suite1 doesn't necessarily look at [Set1] and suite2 won't necessarily look for [Set2]. Other than that inquiry, this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunatelly sets are picked up randomly. At least from what I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use multiple argument files. One containing the first value for ${var} and the other containing the other.

This will execute the same test suite for both argument files.

```
pabot --agumentfile1 varone.args --argumentfile2 vartwo.args file.robot
=>
file.robot executed with varone.args
file.robot executed with vartwo.args
```