# Robot Framework : Test two server in same test cases

Tags: robotframework

I have created files

`valuset.dat`:

```
[Server1]
tags=x.x.x.x
HOST=x.x.x.x
USERNAME=hsiaoi
PASSWORD=yse980327

[Server2]
tags=y.y.y.y
HOST=y.y.y.y
USERNAME=bu11admin
PASSWORD=bu11
```

and `Test suite.dat`

When I execute`pabot --pabotlib --resourcefile .\valueset.dat '.\Test suite.robot'`

Only the first server1 will be tested.

What should I do if I want to test two servers **at the same time**?

Comment: This is the same question as the linked one - that you have asked, with the bolded "twists" they have to be running in parallel. Use that answer, and run the cli commands simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there're two options:

1. You create the same test suite twice and later run your suites like `$ pabot --pabotlib --resourcefile valuset.dat tests`. This way, one test suite will pick up values under `[Server1]`, and the other values under `[Server2]`. The disadvantage is you duplicate code.
2. You can define multiple argument files on the command line like so: `$ pabot --pabotlib --argumentfile1 arg1.txt --argumentfile2 arg2.txt tests`. So you need to create these two argument file:

**arg1.txt**:

```
--variable tags:x.x.x.x
--variable HOST:x.x.x.x
--variable USERNAME:hsiaoi
--variable PASSWORD:yse980327
```

**arg2.txt**:

```
--variable tags:y.y.y.y
--variable HOST:y.y.y.y
--variable USERNAME:bu11admin
--variable PASSWORD:bu11
```

This approach has the advantage that you don't duplicate any code, you have just one test suite and two argument (configuration) files.

You can fine more in this stackoverflow thread: [robot framework with pabot : is it possible to pass two different values to a variable in two tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675475/robot-framework-with-pabot-is-it-possible-to-pass-two-different-values-to-a-va) and in the README file of pabot: https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is it possible to put the values of [Server1] and [Server2] in the same file?

Comment: Point #1 means they are in the same file, but you have to write two test suites. Point #2: I don't see how it could be in one file here. Perhaps there's another even better solution that only I don't know of.