# Pabot: How to use different dataset for each thread

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm trying to Use Pabot to parallelize Robot Tests. Let me explain the issue.

Assume I have `TestA` and `TestB` tests. And `DataA` , `DataB` dataset.

There is 2 way/ goal to use the Pabot.

**1. Run the same test against the different dataset (e.g different mobile devices) / I know this should be done with `--argumentfileX` options flag. So following will be the test runs.**

```
TestA with DataA
TestA with DataB
TestB with DataA
TestB with DataB
```

It's obvious that this is useful when you want to run your test against various Env/Data.

**2. Divide and split the run time. The goal is to reduce the runtime as much as possible, following is the desired**

```
TestA with DataA
TestB with DataB
```

This one (# 2) is my goal. I'm trying this: [robot framework with pabot : is it possible to pass two different values to a variable in two tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675475/robot-framework-with-pabot-is-it-possible-to-pass-two-different-values-to-a-va)

I mean this command:

`pabot --pabotlib --resourcefile Log/pabot_dataset.dat --include test-tag --processes 4 SUITE`

But the problem is Importing `pabot.pabotlib` and `Acquire Value Set` command should exist in every single robot test-cases which has much cost for me to change the robot files as there are thousands tests here.

So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to at least change test suite, you can pass "Acquire Value Set" into Test Setup once so you don't have to change each test case.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    pabot.PabotLib
Test Setup    Assign Value Set  

*** Keywords ***
Assign Value Set
    ${valuesetname}=    Acquire Value Set
    Set Test Variable    ${valuesetname}
```

If you do not want to change test suite files, you can use initialization files. Create `__init__.robot` file in folder where test suites are located and add these lines

```
*** Settings ***
Library    pabot.PabotLib
Test Setup    Acquire Value Set
```

But it has some limitations such as "Variables and keywords created or imported in initialization files are not available in the lower level test suites.".

Comment: Thank you Bobur. I'm looking for a way to don't change robot files.

Comment: Thanks but not help, It doesn't let import the data file and cannot recognize the variables.